# PlatformException (PlatformException(Share callback error, prior share-sheet did not call back, did you await it

Tags: flutter, share

In my case am getting the following error: `PlatformException (PlatformException(Share callback error, prior share-sheet did not call back, did you await it` when using below code:

```
final XFile file = XFile(path);
await Share.shareXFiles([file],
```

but if I use the deprecated method like below (passing the List), the sharing of image works perfectly:

```
await Share.shareFiles([path],
subject: subject,
text: text,
sharePositionOrigin: box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & box.size);
```

`shareFiles` is marked as deprecated but works fine, while following documentation and using `shareXFiles`, throws the plaform exception error:

My environment:

Flutter 3.7.10 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 4b12645012 (9 days ago) • 2023-04-03 17:46:48 -0700
Engine • revision ec975089ac
Tools • Dart 2.19.6 • DevTools 2.20.1

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1**
in Android studio goto : File -> Invalidate Caches -> mark all and restart.
[image]

**Step 2**

[share_plus: ^7.1.0](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) now share xFile.

Share image from Url (Network)

```
              final dir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
                final Response response = await Dio().get(
                  selected,
                  options: Options(
                    responseType: ResponseType.bytes,
                  ),
                );
                final file = File("${dir.path}/Image.png"); // import 'dart:io';
                 file.writeAsBytesSync(Uint8List.fromList(response.data));
                 debugPrint('==> ${file.path}');

                // Share  
                await Share.shareXFiles(
                  [XFile(file.path)],
                );
              },
```

Share from assert/local

```
      onPressed: () async {
                final dir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
                final byte = (await rootBundle.load("assets/images/download.png")).buffer.asUint8List(); // convert in to Uint8List
                debugPrint('byte $byte');
                final file = File("${dir.path}/Image.png") ; // import 'dart:io'
                await file.writeAsBytes(byte);
                // Share
                await Share.shareXFiles(
                  [XFile(file.path)],
                );
              },
```

Comment: Thanks, Android studio goto : File -> Invalidate Caches (*without marking all*) did the trick.

Comment: You can marked all and did it.

Answer (score 1):

I just did `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get` or just run.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by downgrading the share_plus version from 7.0.2 to 7.0.0.

```
  final directoryPath = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
  final imagePath = '$directoryPath/qrimg.png';
  final imageFile = await File(imagePath).create(recursive: true);
  imageFile.writeAsBytesSync(byteData.buffer.asUint8List());

  final file = XFile(imagePath);
  await Share.shareXFiles([file]);
```

Flutter SDK - 3.7.11
Android version 12

Answer (score -1):

shareXFiles function seems to be working with buffer data only. Loading images via rootBundle.load fixes the problem in my case.

```
void share(BuildContext context) async {
    final box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;
    final data = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/example.jpg');
    final buffer = data.buffer;

    await Share.shareXFiles(
      [
        XFile.fromData(
          buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes),
          name: 'example.jpg',
          mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
        ),
      ],
      sharePositionOrigin: box!.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & box.size,
    );
  }
```

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: @PatrickWaweru which error does it emit?