# Can't get gallery access on old version of flutter for Android 13

Tags: flutter, permissions, storage, photo, imagepicker

The application has an image selection function. Before Android 13, everything works fine, but on version 13, no library gives access. This is most likely due to the fact that the project uses Flutter 1.22.0. with version Dart 2.10 (before null safety). I have already added to the manifest the necessary permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="32"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="32" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO"/>
```

I tried the image_picker package, when calling the method, it raises the following error:

```
PlatformException(photo_access_denied, The user did not allow photo access., null, null)
```

So my question is, since switching to a later version of flutter is a rather time-consuming task, is it possible to somehow do without it? Maybe someone already had experience? I'm sure that the point is that the old versions of these libraries are not yet designed to work with Android 13

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your project developed in **flutter version 1.22.0 which was released in 01 Oct 2020**, and after then flutter was upgraded lots of time.

i face same issue in my one major flutter project. it was very complex and big project. we still work on it. **so how we manage our 3 to 3.5 year old project?**

its so much tough to upgrade my project with latest flutter version and plugIn. we now a day when we work on this project we every time downgrade flutter new version to my project applicable flutter version **(in you case downgrade new flutter version to 1.22.0)** and then we work, so no need to upgrade my plugIn/package version time to time.

if you face to problem downgrade flutter version by command like [flutter downgrade  (example: flutter downgrade v1.2.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468321/how-to-downgrade-flutter-sdk-dart-1-x) you can directly download [Flutter SDK](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/archive?tab=windows) and install it as per flutter documentation.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am already using flutter 1.22.0 and I kept getting the above error. Basically, I am using permission_handler flutter package to get gallery access and when I tried to print what Permissions.photo.request is returning, it says granted but for some reason it is not opening the gallery. I am using the following versions tho. 

permission_handler: ^5.1.0+2
image_picker: ^0.6.7+22

Comment: Thank you for response,  For more details will you please provide reference code,  but you call find more help here for storage/photo permission in android 13 and more what my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75298807/storage-permission-in-android-13-flutter/77562074#77562074  and follow this steps in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76003249/platformexception-platformexceptionshare-callback-error-prior-share-sheet-did/76889597#76889597